# Why the split function creates three substrings instead of just two in the following case?

Tags: javascript, regex

Although the following code splits the the given string "hello_world" into "hello" and "world", there is a third **empty string** created. So the ***length*** property shows 3 instead of 2 in the following code. How the third empty string is created although it is not sought?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var str = "hello_world";
 var res = str.split(/_(.+)/);
 alert(res);
 alert(res.length);
</script>
```

Comment: You probably want `str.split(/_/);` What you have now is "split by `_` and any character that appears after it". I'm surprised you didn't end up with "hello" and empty string.

Comment: .. or just `str.split('_')`, but maybe he meant for something when used the capture group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a capture group in the separator regular expression, the matches for the capture group are included in the result of the split.

What's happening is that the regular expression is matching `_world`, so it's splitting the string into `hello` before the separator, and `""` after it. So if you didn't have a capture group (i.e. if the regexp were just `/_.+/`), the result would be

```
["hello", ""]
```

Because you have a capture group, it splices that match in as well. The group matches `world`, so the result becomes

```
["hello", "world", ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern _(.+) matches _ character and one or more character of any type after it, so basically it matches **_world** from your input

But your pattern has a captured group in bracket (), which matches the word **world**, so the word **world** is kept in the result of the split

If you remove the bracket, it's going to use **_world** as separator, and the result is array of length 2, with **hello** and empty string

Comment: I don't see how this explains why there's an empty string at the end of the split.